# Getting the name of file in PHP

Tags: php

How can I get the name of a file in in PHP?   What I want to do is have a function take a string of a filename and then do some stuff if it's actually on the page.

```
function onThisPageFunction(fileNameFromFunction)  
{  
  if(onThisPage == fileNameFromFunction)  
  {  
    do stuff  
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two variables that will give you file names.

eg: you call /test/test1.php as the url and test1.php includes test2.php.

[`__FILE__`](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) will give you the current file of the executing code, in this case it will return "test2.php"

[`$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) will give you the full url of the original call, in this case "/test/test1.php"

Note that you can use the [basename()](http://ca.php.net/basename) function to get just the filename from a path.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly you want `__FILE__`.

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use:

```
_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]
```

eg:

```
    if (isset($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) AND  ($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] == 'foo')){
echo 'do stuff';
}
```

Will

Answer (score 0):

```
if (realpath($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) === __FILE__) {
    echo "Called directly";
}
```

Works on the command line too.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your responses.  This is what ended up doing the job for me.

```
function menuStrikethrough($pageName)
    {
        // get the name of the page we're on
        $fileName = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

        // if fileName equals pageName then output css to show a strikethrough
        if($fileName == $pageName)
        {
            echo ' style="text-decoration:line-through" ';
        }
    }
```

I found `____FILE____` didn't work for me because I wrote this function in an included file.

The basename tip came in handy.

Thanks for all the help!