# Can the php script print back their file name?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting the name of file in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296799/getting-the-name-of-file-in-php)

For example, I a php file called: hello.php

Can I print back the

> hello.php

from code? Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

A `__FILE__` magic consant is evaluated to filename of file it's in. Use `basename(__FILE__)` to get just the filename without path.

See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

`$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` is set to name of currently executed script.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: Keep in mind that \_\_FILE__ is slightly more efficient than $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], since it doesn't involve a key lookup.

Comment: @Polynominal: but it doesn't necessarily contain the same value (e.g. in files included from the executed sscript)

Comment: Ah, yes, very true. `PHP_SELF` gives you the requested script (regardless of includes), `__FILE__` gives you the current executing script. Though, of course, if you're in a script that is never included anywhere (i.e. one only ever directly requested) the `__FILE__` constant is the better choice.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo __FILE__ ;
```

has the full name

Answer (score 2):

Yes, combine the [`__FILE__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) magic constant with [`basename`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php).

```
echo basename(__FILE__);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `basename( __FILE__)`, take a look at [predefined constants in php](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php), there's also lot of interesting information about the script in `$_SERVER`, just use `print_r( $_SERVER);` and study values.

Answer (score 0):

when running in SAPI mode (in a webserver), you can use `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']`. For CLI mode (command line), there's `$argv[0]` ($argv contains the command-line arguments, and element 0 is always the script name).

Answer (score 0):

`$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` gives the path to the running script. This is often a better solution than `__FILE__` because your code may reside in another file imported by the script that is actually running.