# How to get the name of a file as a "string" without the path (to compare with other strings)

Tags: php, file, types

I'm trying to get the name of a file in php, but I'm iterating through an array of files so I don't have the exact path... unless there is a method inside the file that returns the name of the file (or the path, in which I can use `basename()`), which I haven't been able to find. My code looks like this:

```php
foreach ($myfiles as $myfile) {
  // Get name of $myfile here. (Technically as a string)
  if ($myfilename == "Something) {
    // Do something
  }
}
```

I am trying to find the name of the file (`$myfile`) so I can manipulate it as if it were a string.

[Getting the name of file in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296799/getting-the-name-of-file-in-php) is not what I'm looking for, as all the answers imply you have a path, which I do not.

**Basically the php equivalent of Java's: `File.getName()`**

Thank you.

Comment: Is [`basename()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) what you're looking for?

Comment: What's inside `$myfiles`. An 'array of files' doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @Barmar `basename()` takes a path parameter. I don't have the path, just the file as a file. @Evert `$myfiles` is a list of files in a directory. It iterates through the list of files `as files`, not as their names. I'm trying to get the name of `$myfile`.

Comment: What do you mean by "an array of files"? Are they file handles returned by `open()`? The Java function you mention works on open files. If that's what you have, I don't think PHP has an equivalent function.

Comment: When I say an array of files, I mean all of the files in a given directory put into an array. I just am trying to get the name of `$myfile`.

Comment: You have not shown us what is in `$myfiles` (or even how it is declared).

Comment: _"I mean all of the files in a given directory put into an array. "_ - put into an array _as what_? A "file" is an abstract entity, you need to explain what exactly your array contains. List of file _names_, so just strings? Some sort of file _entity_, some class instance that has been created based on the directory entry, to encapsulate some properties of the file, and maybe provide additional methods?

Answer (score 1):

Do you need like this?

```
$file = fopen("File.txt", "r");
// $filename = $file->name; // no way
```

There is **no** method for PHP.

Try this way:

```
<?php

$myfiles = [];
$files = ['fileA.txt', 'fileB.txt'];

foreach($files as $filename) {
    $myfiles[] = ['file' => fopen($filename, "r"), 'filename' => $filename];
}

foreach ($myfiles as $myfile) {
  if ($myfile['filename'] == "Something") {
    // Do something
  }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The method that you are looking for is [pathinfo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php).

It returns an array with information about the file, the `filename` index has the name of the file.

Comment: Read the question, I don't have the path.

Comment: It's not required to have the path, just the filename is enough. See the examples returned by the function in the docs linked, if it helps.